# Android AsyncTask. Возможен ли вызов нескольких execute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Я пытаюсь создать примитивный клиент, который при нажатии на одну из 4-х кнопок будет отправлять соответстующее сообщение на сервер. Выношу задачу отправки сообщения в отдельный поток, используя AsyncTask. В обработчиках нажатий на кнопки находится следующее `new ControllerTask().execute("button1");` При первом нажатии всё работает отлично, но как только происходит второе нажатие (независимо от очерёдности кнопок) активити вылетает и меня перебрасывает на главную активити моего приложения (из за чего я не могу отловить логи данной ошибки).

Код моего AsyncTack класса:

```
class ControllerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String ... params) {
        try {
            //отправка сообщения серверу

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Я пробовал не создавать каждый раз новый объект класса ControllerTask, но ошибка сохранилась.

Буду благодарен помощи.

Comment: Странно, что логи не видать. Должны оставаться. Вы делаете правильно - нужен новый экземпляр на новую задачу. Надо таки как-то логи получить - без этого ничего поделать нельзя.

Comment: AsyncTask объявлен как deprecated. Я советую вам перейти на RX

Comment: либо Coroutine использовать